# Ember: Provide template name for nested route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Due to my build tool of choice currently I cannot name templates with slashes (like `ads/index`). This is hopefully going to change soon, but I'm interested what's wrong with my app anyway.

Here're my routes:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'ads', ->
    @route 'index', path: '/'
    @route 'create'
```

I also have `App.AdsRoute` and `App.AdsController` defined (their content most probably doesn't matter, currently they fetch data for the `ads.index` — a list of ads).

My `ads` template only contains an `outlet`

```
= outline
```

(it's Emblem)

Finally, I have an `ads_index` and `ads_create` templates with some meaningful content. Now I obviously want them to render when visiting `#/ads` and `#/ads/create` respectively.

So, first I define

```
AdsView: Ember.View.extend
    templateName: 'ads_index'
```

Now when I visit `#/ads` it shows what I need. But when I click a link to `ads.create` it still shows the same ads list but the links get the 'active' class.

I assume that AdsView worked as a wildcard view for the whole `ads` resource.

So, I renamed all the things: AdsRoute -> AdsIndexRoute, AdsController -> AdsIndexController, AdsView -> AdsIndexView.

Now the page is empty. I see the router and controller are still doing their job sending the proper AJAX request. But the view is not rendering. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [log](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_log) helper and log `this`:

```
{{log this}}
```

Are you able to view the properties of the model you're passing to the view? It might help to throw this in a jsFiddle so we can debug it.

Comment: the template is not redering, where am I expected to add this log? quite difficult to move to fiddle, lots of coffeescript, emblem, requirejs and stuff

Comment: sorry, found a typo in the master template :(

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. It was a typo in "ads.emblem" - outline instead of outlet.